# Zero-width non-joiners and and zero-width space inserted in code

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code

Please look at my comments to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13716/30810:

They cannot be copied and compiled because there are zero-width non-joiners and and zero-width spaces (`&zwnj;&#8203;` in HTML source code) inserted in the code snippets. (You also see weird behavior in some text editors when you copy and paste this.) After the first two times, I thought this might have been the result of copy-and-pasting this from somewhere, so the third time, I typed the whole comment without pasting from anywhere. Interestingly, these things appear mid-word in different places. Is this a browser bug (Windows 10, Chrome, 58.0.3029.110), or is this a results os TeX.SX processing?

Comment: Looks like this has come up elsewhere [Occasionally, the Unicode character sequence U+200C U+200B (ZWNJ ZWSP) is inserted into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970) and [Invisible unicode characters inside code comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348600) and there's a recent feature request on Meta.SX [Stop inserting invisible characters into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295425)

Comment: A workaround is to insert spaces in the comment wherever possible, so that there are no long runs (>80 characters?) without spaces.

Comment: As mentioned in the related posts elsewhere, this is [tag:status-bydesign]. It's either that, or comments not breaking and overflowing. In order to truly fix this we'll have to rebuild the whole comment layout, so that it's not based on tables.